# Searching for unmatched ntheames when comparing spreadsheets

Tags: compare, excel-formula

In one spreadsheet I have 3 columns with a first and last name of a person combined.  In the 2nd spreadsheet, I have column a = first name and column b = last name.

I want to know which names in spreadsheet one cannot be found in spreadsheet two.  I also need to verify the data to make sure that the formula was accurate on finding the correct lookup.

Do I have to combine my columns in spreadsheet 2 to make the first and last name in the same column to make this work?

Which formula would you use for either scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=ISNA(MATCH($A1&" "&$B1,Sheet2!$A:$A,FALSE)))
```

Where (in order):

- `A1` is the first name column in `Sheet1`
- `B1` is the last name column in `Sheet1`
- `Sheet2` is the sheet that has the data stored as names separately
- `$A:$A` is the rows that have the two names together
- `FALSE` is because it's an exact match

This will return `FALSE` if the element does not exist, and `TRUE` if it does

You can also use:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1&" "&$B1,Sheet2!$A:$D,3,FALSE)
```

If you want to retrieve data for a match.

Finally, if you need to do your lookups the other way, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031305/simulate-string-split-function-in-excel-formula) for some ideas on how to split the string into two pieces.