# How can I delimit with characters using vba?

Tags: vba, delimiter

Example: consider there are 5 names separated with a semicolon. I want to separate these 5 names.
consider,
Richard;Pareek;Elizabeth;Creig;Tomy

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031305/simulate-string-split-function-in-excel-formula

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [`Split()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Example:

```
Dim input as String
Dim results() as String

input = "Richard;Pareek;Elizabeth;Creig;Tomy"
results = Split(input,";")
```

*Note:* If there are are spaces after the semicolons, be sure to include that in the second parameter of the `Split` function (so `"; "` instead of `";"`)